# Extjs 4 newline character in column header text

Tags: extjs, extjs4.1, extjs-mvc

In my grid columns header/text are very long and I want to display it in 2-3 line, depends on requirement. Customer will put all this entry in a file with "\n" as new line character.

How to implment it in Extjs 4.1???

Note : 'br/>' works fine but all files created by end user with "\n" not with 'br>'.

Thanks.

Comment: You need to transform any newline characters to `<br>`.

Comment: Hi Evan, where can i do this?? is there any property in GridPanel or have to override class?? Bcoz "render" function invoked for grid data rows.

Answer (score 3):

Use `cls` property for the column:

```
columns: [{
    header: 'Multiline',
    dataIndex: 'MyProp',
    cls: 'multiline'
}]
```

And then modify css file

```
.multiline .x-column-header-inner .x-column-header-text { white-space: normal; }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can set this property in your css style:

```
.x-column-header-inner .x-column-header-text { white-space: pre-wrap; }
```

Pre-wrap info: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_white-space.asp

Comment: Thanks for prompt reply, I works, but It also wrap other columns which are not specified and does not even contain next line character. Any idea???